# how to destroy graphics content?

Tags: java, rectangles

How do I make shapes to burst or disappear when it intersects with a rectangle2D(bullet). Bursting will be preferable since I am developing a shooting game. I want the rectangle to burst or disappear when the bullet (another rectangle) intersects or hits it. Someone please help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please do not ask the identical question multiple times - instead try to improve your original question via editing. If you can make it meet the site-standards it might get reopened.

Comment: Have a look into particle effects

Comment: Thanks much......but I think that is  a little bit advance for what am working on right now

Answer (score 1):

Burst: you replace `Rectangle` object with 4 lines that make up the rectangle and move them in different directions, thus creating burst effect.

Disappear: you simply stop drawing the `Rectangle` object once it collides